# WORLDPAY Integration using php

Tags: php, payment-gateway

Can any one please let me know is `WORLDPAY` payment gateway provides API for php stuffs? did any of you integrates this stuff? please advise me....

Comment: I have given you a simple and step by step tutorial for implementation.          http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/08/worldpay-payment-gateway-integration-php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find complete documentation here: [RBS WorldPay Technical Guides](http://www.rbsworldpay.com/support/bg/index.php?page=guides&c=UK)

A simple payment submission would look like this:

```
<form action="https://secure.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/wcc/purchase" method=POST>
    <input type=hidden name="instId" value="yourid">
    <input type=hidden name="cartId" value="cartid">
    <input type=hidden name="amount" value="9.99">
    <input type=hidden name="currency" value="GBP">
    <input type=submit value="Buy Now">    
</form>
```

Comment: from where we get "instId"?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation and detailed way of implementing worldpay is redirection is explained [in worldpay integration techniques](http://integrate-payment-gateway.blogspot.com/2011/12/integrate-worldpay-payment-gateway.html)  and xml way or the api way of integrating is described in [worldpay xml integration](http://integrate-payment-gateway.blogspot.com/2012/01/worldpay-direct-xml-integration-php.html)
like

```
<paymentService version="1.4" merchantCode="WPACC11112222">
<submit>
    <order orderCode="T021101078">
          <description>20 Tulip Bulbs from MYMERCHANT Webshops</description>
          <amount value="2600" currencyCode="EUR" exponent="2"/>
          <paymentDetails>
              <VISA-SSL>
                  <cardNumber>4444333322221111</cardNumber>
                  <expiryDate>
                      <date month="09" year="2015"/>
                  </expiryDate>
                  <cardHolderName>Akhilraj</cardHolderName>
                  <cvc>123</cvc>
                  <cardAddress>
                      <address>
                           <street>47A Queensbridge Rd</street>
                           <postalCode>CB94BQ</postalCode>
                           <countryCode>GB</countryCode>
                      </address>
                  </cardAddress>
               </VISA-SSL>
               <session shopperIPAddress="'.$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].'" id="0215ui8ib1" />
          </paymentDetails>
          <shopper>
              <shopperEmailAddress>dfgdf@gmail.com</shopperEmailAddress>
              <browser>
                   <acceptHeader>'.$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'].'</acceptHeader>
                   <userAgentHeader>'.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'</userAgentHeader>
               </browser>
           </shopper>
    </order>
```

';